# Why is my Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My bootstrap Navbar is not collapsing when I click the 3 bars when the screen is too small for the nav bar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here are my links

```
  <link href="bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a meta viewport for mobile devices.

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle for a sample page of your site? I'm sure it's some minor thing to be worked out.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy. The bootstrap documentation for that can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

Comment: @MichaelPlotke No prob, I'm glad it helped someone. OP is still a mystery though...