# bootstrap dropdown menu with hamburger menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a webpage with wordpress and bootstrap, and i want to make a dropdown menu with categories , but when the page is resized (ex for phone size) , i want the menu to change into 'hamburger menu' , like in the images below .. 
My problem is that the "hamburger menu " dont show the categories separately , but the dropdown menu like in the image 3 .. is there any way to fix that ?

[image: In full size]

[image: In mobile size]

[image: dropdown in hamburger menu]

Answer (score 1):

If it's not automatically stacking menus you may need to add a meta viewport.

Link to discussion and documentation:

[Why is my Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095425/why-is-my-bootstrap-navbar-not-collapsing/31095426#31095426)